# If test subjects inside a lab-experiment-universe figured out how to use the Help Desk, what form would the technology take?

Tags: internal-consistency, magic, technological-development, alternate-worlds

A technologically advanced non-humanoid species discovers trans-universal travel and use their (relatively new at the time) universe-hopping tech to escape a world-killer asteroid, taking with them an ark of familiar plants and beasts.

They discover that they didn't so much as find a universe as inadvertently make one for themselves, so they get on a trip where they custom design their own universes.  Some are for industrial purposes, some are for recreational or simply lifestyle purposes, while, of course, some are experimental.

My story is about one of those experimental universes.

The inhabitants have a fairly high technology, about where we are now (with some differences, and maybe more advanced in some respects); it's more fantasy, though, than strictly sci-fi sort of tech. They were given, or stumbled onto early, the digital helper the "gods" left to monitor the universe, and their technology revolves around developing devices and skills that can make use of this AI (in the same way users can write skills for Alexa, or maybe even build something practical that it can use, ie, a sort of distributed AI.)

The question then is what would such a technology - one that relies upon accessing the Help Desk AI, and whatever limited scripting the test subjects somehow have permission to use - look like physically?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Here we strive to solve specific problems, not to discuss around idea for the sake of discussing. We are not a forum. Also, brush off the non necessary part. It's hard to go through an introduction to the introduction of the question.

Comment: They have General Electric laboratories?

Comment: Welcome to the site PR.  As @L.Dutch mentioned here we work specific questions with specific answers.  Check out the [tour] and [help] to get a better idea of how the site works.  Good luck with your project, your world idea is interesting.

Comment: So you have a virtual reality universe with a help desk interface.  The interface may not be intentional.  You're asking what it looks like inside the universe.  I think that the problem that you're having is that it might look like anything.  Turn this around.  How would you like it to appear?  It's virtual reality, we can almost certainly justify any appearance that you want to write.

Comment: @Brythan : I don't think OP is talking about VR (you can't escape an extinction event asteroid by hopping into VR), unless I'm misreading his post this is a real universe created by technologically advanced aliens.